# 3d particle filter based slam

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys ,

I am aware of 2d slam using AMCL . Where 2d laser scans are compared with a global cost map to restimate the location .

I was wondering if there might be  any algorithm out there which can do the following .

- **First build a highly dense Point Cloud Map** using a 3D lidar such as VLP16 .(I used this , https://github.com/ningwang1028/lidar_slam_3d)
- **Then using the above generated  map , use depth output from Stereo/Depth camera  to perform a 3d particle filter** to re-estimate the location

If anyone has some pointers kindly share .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338081/3d-particle-filter-based-slam/) by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2019-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure, doesn't sound too hard, it would be the exact same process as AMCL just with a different projection model of the rays. All the algorithms you just mentioned you gave examples of existing, its just plugging them together to make your application.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1